# access preloaded images

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have found a script [here](http://engineeredweb.com/blog/09/12/preloading-images-jquery-and-javascript) that preloads images, but I dont know how can to access them.

```
(function($) {
  var cache = [];
  // Arguments are image paths relative to the current page.
  $.preLoadImages = function() {
    var args_len = arguments.length;
    for (var i = args_len; i--;) {
      var cacheImage = document.createElement('img');
      cacheImage.src = arguments[i];
      cache.push(cacheImage);
    }
  }
})(jQuery)
```

In other words I would take chace[i] - when the preload finished - and append to a div. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`load`](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) event. Example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/karalamalar/ZK7pe/).

HTML:

```
<div id="test"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
(function($) {
  var cache = [];
  // Arguments are image paths relative to the current page.
  $.preLoadImages = function() {
    var args_len = arguments.length;
    for (var i = args_len; i--;) {
      var cacheImage = document.createElement('img');
      cacheImage.src = arguments[i];
      cache.push(cacheImage);
      $(cacheImage).load(function() {
          if(cache.length == args_len) {
              $(cache).each(function() {
                  $('#test').append(this);
              });
          }
      });
    }
  }
  $.preLoadImages(
      "http://images.free-extras.com/pics/c/car-530.jpg",
      "http://images.free-extras.com/pics/c/car-529.jpg",
      "http://images.free-extras.com/pics/c/cars-528.jpg"
  );
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: do you know how can I achieve that the append fires if all pictures loaded?

Comment: Updated my answer. Check it out.

Comment: Nice, you can also append each image as soon as it's done loading, this way if one image fails to load it won't stop the other images from showing up. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MjJVg/).